# Class in Folder autoloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces

In one of my controllers I would like to use a Service-Class that I located inside of: `services/cars/strategies/unload_car_strategy.rb`

Although the `unload_car_strategy.rb` is located inside the folders, I don't want to use namespacing: The class right now looks like this:

```
class UnloadCarStrategy
  ....
end
```

When I call in my controller `UnloadCarStrategy.new`  I get the error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant UnloadCarStrategy
```

**How can I instruct Rails to load this Class?**

Answer (score 0):

By default everything under your app/ dir gets auto- and eager- loaded when your application starts. So you got your services dir loaded when the application started.

Even though if you add as many folders and files in those folders you want, Rails will load them for you until you follow the namespacing.

Since you are not using the namespacing the class `UnloadCarStrategy` doesn't get loaded.

You have to explicitly require it either in the respective controller where it is needed or in the application.rb file.

you either add
`require "#{Rails.root}/app/services/cars/strategies/unload_car_strategy"` in the controller from where it has to be called
or add the below line to application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W({config.root}/app/services/cars/strategies/unload_car_strategy.rb)
```

source : https://gist.github.com/maxim/6503591#if-you-add-a-dir-under-appsomething